# Used symbol for Mediant?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

Some little introduction: in Naïve-Bayes algorithm for clasification the Laplace correction or Laplace smoothing formula is $$ P(a|M) = \frac{n(a,M)+1}{n(M)+|\Omega_A|} $$ when the original formula for calculate the probability of $P(a|M)$ is $$ P(a|M) = \frac{n(a,M)}{n(M)} $$ so the addition of $ \frac{1}{|\Omega_A|} $ do not follow the common sumation for fractions (I mean, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}$ you basically need to do $\frac{1 \cdot 3+1\cdot2}{2 \cdot 3}$), my question is: there is a symbol for represent this Mediant summation?

Edit: I found in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hlvhQZIOQw in the minute 2:35 that he uses "xor" or "oplus" ($\oplus$) to represent it, but I couldn't find any other reference about this...

Comment: It may be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011484/is-there-an-operator-for-adding-the-numerator-and-denominator-of-a-fraction-sepa. The operation is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics). You asked for a symbol, so knowing the name of the operation may not suffice.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, I completly forgot about the Farey sequence... Thanks!

Comment: You asked for a symbol. The other question didn't.